# Select stops at error 537, but I want it to continu with the next rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
BEGIN TRY
    (
        SELECT TOP 30
            [Row Number] AS NO,
            SUBSTRING([HTMLBody], patindex('%factuur%', [HTMLBody]) + 8, patindex('%van leverancier%', [HTMLBody]) - patindex('%factuur%', [HTMLBody]) - 9) AS Test1,
            SUBSTRING([HTMLBody], patindex('%leverancier%', [HTMLBody]) + 12, patindex('% - %', [HTMLBody]) - patindex('%leverancier%', [HTMLBody]) - 12) AS Test2,
            SUBSTRING([HTMLBody], patindex('% - %', [HTMLBody]) + 3, patindex('%kon niet%', [HTMLBody]) - patindex('% - %', [HTMLBody]) - 3) AS Test3
        FROM [ErrorDB].[dbo].[Error]
    )
    END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS Error,
        ERROR_STATE(),
        ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        ERROR_LINE(),
        ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
        ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        GETDATE();
    PRINT 'Error'
END CATCH

GO
```

The code above extracts data from a HTML record. But on row 19 it stops and raises a error. I know the error so I want the query to continue whiteout stopping. I already tried allot whitout result. How to??

Comment: What error? Which dbms?

Comment: Write your query so it can't fail. `SUBSTRING` does not accept negative lengths; if your string doesn't contain the patterns, you end up passing a negative length. Use `CASE`/`IIF` and/or `STUFF` to manipulate the string in a more robust way. You cannot make the server simply ignore errors and continue with other rows; query processing doesn't work that way.

Comment: You could add a "where" clause to your query of the "Error" table. If you filtered out any rows that are causing the error, would that still give you all the error data you need to query? Otherwise, as Jeroen stated, you cannot make SQL Server ignore such an error. There is no code or switch or option or config to bypass errors (which is what I think you are looking for). If possible, just identify the problematic rows and filter them out of the query with a "where" clause or as Jeroen stated by improving your "select" clause to properly handle the problematic data.

Answer (score 0):

I have improved the while loop performance, you can use this query to capture error.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp_Error
(
    [Row Number] NUMERIC(18,0),
    [HTMLBody] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

CREATE TABLE #Temp_Error_Log
(
    [Row Number] NUMERIC(18,0),
    [HTMLBody] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

CREATE TABLE #Temp_Error_Desc
(
    [Row Number] NUMERIC(18,0),
    Test1 NVARCHAR(2000),
    Test2 NVARCHAR(2000),
    Test3 NVARCHAR(2000),
) 

INSERT INTO #Temp_Error
(
    [Row Number],[HTMLBody]
)
SELECT [Row Number],[HTMLBody] 
FROM [ErrorDB].[dbo].[Error]

DECLARE @BATCH INT=100,@N_TOTAL INT

SELECT @BATCH=Count(1) FROM #TEMP_ERROR

SELECT @N_TOTAL=@BATCH

WHILE @BATCH>0
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY

            ;WITH CTE AS
            (
                SELECT TOP (@BATCH)
                [Row Number],
                SUBSTRING([HTMLBody], patindex('%factuur%', [HTMLBody]) + 8, patindex('%van leverancier%', [HTMLBody]) - patindex('%factuur%', [HTMLBody]) - 9) AS Test1,
                SUBSTRING([HTMLBody], patindex('%leverancier%', [HTMLBody]) + 12, patindex('% - %', [HTMLBody]) - patindex('%leverancier%', [HTMLBody]) - 12) AS Test2,
                SUBSTRING([HTMLBody], patindex('% - %', [HTMLBody]) + 3, patindex('%kon niet%', [HTMLBody]) - patindex('% - %', [HTMLBody]) - 3) AS Test3
                FROM #Temp_Error
            )

            DELETE b
            OUTPUT DELETED.*
            INTO   #Temp_Error_Desc ([Row Number],Test1,Test2,Test3)
            FROM   CTE b

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

            IF @BATCH<>@N_TOTAL
            BEGIN

                ;WITH CTE AS
                (
                    SELECT TOP (@BATCH) *
                    FROM #Temp_Error
                )

                DELETE b
                OUTPUT DELETED.*
                INTO   #Temp_Error_Log ([Row Number],[HTMLBody])
                FROM   CTE b

            END

            ELSE 
            BEGIN
                SET @BATCH=IIF(@BATCH<10,1,@BATCH/10)
            END

    END CATCH

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #Temp_Error)
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO #Temp_Error
            (
                [Row Number],[HTMLBody]
            )
            SELECT [Row Number],[HTMLBody]
            FROM #Temp_Error_Log

            TRUNCATE TABLE #Temp_Error_Log

            IF @BATCH=1
            BEGIN
                SET @BATCH=0
            END
            ELSE
                SET @BATCH=IIF(@BATCH<10,1,@BATCH/10)
        END
END


SELECT * FROM #Temp_Error
SELECT * FROM #Temp_Error_Desc

DROP TABLE #Temp_Error
DROP TABLE #Temp_Error_Log
DROP TABLE #Temp_Error_Desc
```

Comment: Oh dear...this is not a good way to solve this problem at all. Looping is not something you want to do. This is just dealing with a sloppy code in a lazy way. Fix the query, not find a way to hide the problem.

Comment: Row by row processing is very inefficient; doubly so when it's done this way instead of cursors (which are also bad, but at least the most efficient way to go about things if you *are* doing row by row processing).

Comment: Hello all, This is working fine for me. I was not shure how to use the substring query, so it stops bcs the patern I was searching for was not in some records, thats why the error raises. So i tryed the WHERE option before the SUBSTRING statement and that was also a good way to get no error messages. But the last script was a good one that returns alle records  with or without errors. Thnks for the quick reply.

Comment: Hi @SeanLange now I've implemented the while loop with batch by batch Processing.is this ok for better performance ??.